# How to build long horizontal blocks in Terraria on XBox?

Tags: terraria-console

Some constructions in Terraria, for example [SkyBridge](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Skybridge), require the construction of long horizontal blocks.

I only played the game on XBox and presume that building such blocks on a PC might be easier using mouse to position your pointer, but on XBox this is almost undoable: once I have some blocks aligned horizontally and my hero is standing on them, it requires a delicate balance between hero going further towards the brink and cursor in the opposite direction so that the blinking building block (marking the position where a new block is going to be put) is at the right place.

Even after some practice it takes me about a minute to build only 5 blocks (!). Taking into account the size of the Terraria world, this makes the task of Skybridge construction on console almost impossible.

Is it so by design or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found creating sky bridges on the mobile platform to be the most difficult, However on the PS3/Xbox version, press the right along stick in, this will allow you to go into build mode, this makes placing tiles a lot easier.

Its still going to take ages to make a skybridge in a large world

Comment: Pressing right joystick works just wonderfully, thank you a lot for this hint!